# Is it possible to embed Google Drive Spreadsheet Engine on my page?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-sheets

Is there any js library that allows to embed spreadsheet (exactly the same as on Google Drive) on custom page? I don't mean to create spreadsheet on google Drive and embed it on my page. What I need is download js library, attach it to my page, create div for spreadsheet, and trigger some function that will show spreadsheet on that div.

So I need only to access to engine of spreadsheet, not to create files on google drive.

Answer (score -1):

You can publish any documents, spreadsheet, or presentation to public web.
Here is some details of how to do publish document: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37579?hl=en. Just publish your spreadsheet and you will get public url which you can push in with iframe.